# Handling of C++ initialization and multithread aware functions that require a mutex before main() gets called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization

So my concern is hitting a function which creates a thread before `main()` gets called. At that point, thread safe functions need to have a mutex which is ready. Only, there is no way to guarantee the order in which global objects get initialized in C++ (well, to some extend, we can, but still, in a large project, good luck with that!)

So I like to have my global objects, such as singletons, allocated at runtime. That way, they get initialized the first time you call their `instance()` function and that means they are ready when needed. However, if I have two or more threads running, they may each end up creating an instance unless I make sure to have a valid lock in that function.

I want to make sure that using the following initialization:

```
pthread_mutex_t global_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

always happen at compile time and thus that `global_mutex` is always going to be ready for `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

This means my singleton (and other classes that need initialization before `main()` gets called) can rely on that mutex as in the following simplified code:

```
// singleton.h
class singleton
{
public:
    static singleton * instance();

    ...other functions...

private:
    singleton();
};

// singleton.cpp
pthread_mutex_t global_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

singleton *  global_singleton = nullptr;

singleton::singleton()
{
    // do some initialization
}

singleton * singleton::instance()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_mutex);  // <- works even before main() called?
    if(global_singleton == nullptr)
    {
        global_singleton = new singleton();
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_mutex);
    return global_singleton;
}
```

*Note: I'm not asking about the validity of the singleton pattern. Just about the mutex. Also, no, you can't safely use a smart pointer in the global variable because you can't know whether it will be initialized before you call the `instance()` function. If you want to return a smart pointer, you can always use a bare pointer to a smart pointer. It doesn't change much anything for the singleton. It still won't get destroyed automatically.*

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, function-`static` variables are *required* by the standard to be initialized in a thread-safe fashion. How the implementation pulls that off is up to it, but the compiler is required to generate something to ensure thread safety.

So you can do this:

```
singleton * singleton::instance()
{
    static auto global_singleton = new singleton();
    return global_singleton;
}
```

Of course, you must understand that complex interactions of these "somethings" that make `static` initialization thread-safe may well lead to deadlocks. This is yet another reason why the singleton pattern should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the `pthread_once` mechanism which is designed to provide a guaranteed one-time initialisation for libraries:

- [`pthread_once`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_once.html)

Adapting your example, something like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_once_t lib_is_initialized = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
statec pthread_mutex_t global_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void initialise_lib()
{
   pthread_mutex_init(&global_mutex, NULL);
}

singleton * singleton::instance()
{
    pthread_once(&lib_is_initialized, initialize_lib);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&global_mutex);
    if(global_singleton == nullptr)
    {
        global_singleton = new singleton();
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&global_mutex);
    return global_singleton;
}
```

However this is more complex than necessary. You can rely on the safe initialisation of a static variable being performed once, so I would recommend using the simpler solution posted by @Nicol Bolas.

Comment: Actually, I like the idea, but I would initialize the singleton inside the `initialize_lib()` function. That would make more sense, I think. And I would not need the `global_mutex` (the `lib_is_initialized` object certainly has a mutex already.)